# How remove gray highlight in kable() table and distinct rows by a line based on one variable?

Tags: r, knitr, kable

I have the following dataframe:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

df<-structure(list(variable = c("A", "B", "B","B"), area = c("BMW", "Lexus", "Toyota", "Honda"), 
               Previous_week = c(3.6,2, 32.2, 49.8), delta = c(-1.3, -2.5, -3.5, -0.3), 
               delta_prcnt = c("-16.4%","-5.6%", "-9.8%", "-0.7%")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then I created a table with the following code

```
df  %>% 
  kable(col.names = c(" ","Area","Value","Delta","delta %"), caption = "Title of the table") %>%  #$\Delta$
  kable_paper("striped", full_width = F) %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  column_spec(4:5, bold = T, color = "black", background = ifelse(df$BMW >= 0, "#C6EFCE", "#FFC7CE")) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " =1, "Area and value" = 2, "Change" = 2)) %>%
  collapse_rows(1, valign="middle")
```

I want to make the following changes:

1. Several cells are highlighted with gray color, how can I remove this highlight?
2. How can I differentiate groups A and B by line based on column `variable` (make bottom/top borders for specific cells)?
3. How can I make horizontal lines below the columns' names black (bold black)?
4. I know that `kable()` affords writing characters as Greek letters, I want that column names Delta to have it. I tried using `$\Delta$`, however got an error.

Comment: Can you include the libraries and other options you are using? Certainly you've got `kableExtra`, what else? The gray highlighting appears to be a symptom of either some library or option, because I didn't reproduce it when using your MWE.

Comment: I'm also not sure what you're asking to do with request #2. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: The code is not reproducible; `df_hydrology` is not defined. Are you knitting to html or pdf format?

Comment: I added all necessary libraries, #2 is updated, the data frame is changed to another one that is why it is not working.

Comment: It's still not quite reproducible, but I think you just mean for `df_hydrology` to be simply `df`. However, @Peter had a good question that I don't think you've addressed: are you creating an .html or a .pdf output? (I suspect .html)

Comment: Sorry, just notice what he meant, now should be correct. Here I am creating HTML output, but if it will be in pdf, it will also work well